# change HTTP headers of Chrome and Firefox

Tags: macos, terminal, google-chrome, firefox

Browsers send HTTP Accept headers. This is an example of one:

```
text/html, */*; q=0.01 gzip, deflate en-US,en;q=0.8,sl;q=0.6
```

You can get yours [here](https://panopticlick.eff.org/).

How can I change curent headers from terminal app for Chrome or Firefox?

EDIT:

Forefox has a collection(dictionary) of `user_pref`'s you can set in `prefs.js`. However you first need to know the correct entry you are setting. Is there a list of all entries developer can set?

Comment: To what do you want to change it? Do you want to change it for one HTTP request or by default? Why does it need to be via Terminal and not directly in the respective browser (which probably would be easier)?

Comment: To different quality scores, use different compression and see how the server handles it. Why Terminal? Imagine changing parameters over a broader set of values.

Comment: In Firefox you can use the add-on "Tamper Data" - http://tamperdata.mozdev.org/ - where you can modify the header - but this isn't from a terminal.